# AppEngine Flex Node.js timeout error 4 when deploying

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Whenever I try to deploy my updated AppEngine node.js website (was node 6.14.x, but I've updated to 12.x as part of my attempts to fix this) I am getting a timeout error. Running the site locally, or on the Google Cloud Shell works fine immediately and I can hit the health check url too.

I usually use the Google Cloud Shell to deploy my prod environment, but have also tried from my local machine and got the same results. In either case, for days I've been getting this error:

```
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned.
```

On one attempt from the Google Cloud Shell I got the following error:

```
Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.
```

I tried updating the app_start_timeout_sec to 600 and got the same error `"Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section."`

Then I tried updating it to 1800 and just got the original `"ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy."`

Obviously each deploy just takes longer to fail.

Verbose logging from the deploy doesn't really show anything useful, but see below. I'm not sure if there are other places I should be looking for clues, but from poking around nothing is jumping out as an issue.

I have looked at several tickets on the Google Issue Tracker (e.g. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73583699) and tried some of the suggestions, but I don't see anything wrong (nothing in logs about resources, noting in settings about quotas being reached.) I opened a ticket there but they closed it saying

> "I tried to reproduce the issue on my end by making a few App Engine
> deployments but couldn't get to the error message you experienced.
> Moreover, I haven't found other cases or issues reporting the same
> behavior, so as of now the issue seems isolated to your environment."

Caveats: This is apparently the first deploy I've attempted to production in 2020, so maybe something changed that I need to do? Looks like 2019-10-12 was the last build.

So, any hints on what I can do to find the error, or how I can resolve it?

Thanks for the help.

**app.yaml**

(Update, I've also tried commenting out the readiness_check section, but it makes no difference).

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 5
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.8
readiness_check:
  path: "/health"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  FIREBASE_SERVICE_PROJECT_ID: 'blah'
  FIREBASE_SERVICE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID: 'blah'
  FIREBASE_SERVICE_PRIVATE_KEY: "blah"
  FIREBASE_SERVICE_CLIENT_EMAIL: 'blah'
  FIREBASE_SERVICE_CLIENT_ID: 'blah'
  FIREBASE_SERVICE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL: 'blah'
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: 'blah'
  AUTH_SECRET: 'blah'
  AUTH_USERNAME: 'blah'
  AUTH_PASSWORD: 'blah'
  LEAGUE_TABLE_URL: 'blah'
# [END runtime]
```

**Verbose "gcloud app deploy" log**

```
...
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...⠏DEBUG: Operation [apps/daggers-72eb6/operations/b7ef6a92-1ce7-457a-a85a-ef32ae235cf9] not complete. Waiting to retry.       
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...⠏DEBUG: Operation [apps/daggers-72eb6/operations/b7ef6a92-1ce7-457a-a85a-ef32ae235cf9] complete. Result: {                   
    "done": true,
    "error": {
        "code": 4,
        "message": "Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned."
    },
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
        "insertTime": "2020-07-14T22:46:01.763Z",
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
        "target": "apps/blah/services/default/versions/20200714t154223",
        "user": "blah"
    },
    "name": "apps/blah/operations/blah"
}
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                      
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 808, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 117, in Run
    default_strategy=flex_image_build_option_default))
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 651, in RunDeploy
    ignore_file=args.ignore_file)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 437, in Deploy
    extra_config_settings)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 208, in DeployService
    poller=done_poller)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 314, in WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=retry_interval)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 264, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms, _StatusUpdate)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 326, in PollUntilDone
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 229, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "/Users/ashleydb/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 183, in IsDone
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(operation.error)))
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned.
```

**Updates**

Everything works fine locally. Here is a list of things I have tried, none of which have resolved the deployment issue:

- Enabling split health checks
- Commenting out this readiness_check section of the app.yaml
- Updating packages which were pretty old, including node 6->12, webpack 1->4 and latest @google-cloud/error-reporting & @google-cloud/storage APIs.
- Setting this up as a whole new GCP project in a new region

Comment: Looking deeper, I suspect this may be the issue (a change in the way health checks are now done): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#updated_health_checks

Comment: Do you have a url handler for `/health`?

Comment: Yes, I've had that handler for a long time. I've updated it to ensure 200 codes are returned every time now to try and debug this, but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved. Turns out one of the env vars I had configured in my app.yaml (a private key for accessing firebase) had been changed from being wrapped in single quotes to double quotes ('blah' to "blah") which was enough to break the variable apparently.

The fact that everything worked locally but not when deploying was pointing at the app.yaml for sure, but it was frustrating to not get any other error output about why the instance wasn't starting up.

Answer (score 0):

You have set up your `readiness_check` to go to the url `/health`:

```
readiness_check:
  path: "/health"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

Make sure you have a URL handler for that, so that if you navigate to yourapp.appspot.com/health, it returns a valid 200 response.

Comment: Yes, I've had a handler for that. I've just updated the handler to always ensure the response is definitely 200 to help narrow this down but it hasn't helped so far.
I've also made sure to enable split health checks as per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/migrating-to-split-health-checks

Comment: So if you manually navigate to `/health`, you get a 200, with no trailing slash or other redirect?

Comment: Correct, yes I do.

Comment: In fact, I just tried commenting out this section of the app.yaml and still get the same error.

Comment: This sounds more like a deeper problem, like one of your required packages isn't available.  Everything works fine in development?  Have you tried all URLs?  Perhaps some strange typo in package.json?  Try getting latest versions of all packages.

Comment: Everything works fine locally. I don't see anything weird in package.json. I spent the day updating packages which were pretty old, including node 12, webpack 4 and latest google-cloud error reporting & storage. But still seeing the same error.

Comment: I've just tried setting this up as a whole new GCP project in a new region and STILL get the same result.

Comment: Check your billing account.  https://console.cloud.google.com/billing  Perhaps your credit card expired since last deploy, so you cannot use the flex environment.  It has no free tier.

Comment: Nice idea, but my CC details look good through to 2021.